# For statement to loop through an array and array items to new arrays based off pattern recognition append matched

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not getting the results that I would have expected from this function. What I expected is that I would have four arrays with multiple items in them. But instead, I'm getting undefined for everything in the console. Here are my instructions for the function:

> Your job is to loop over this array and put items with similarities into four brand new arrays using regular expressions and the Array.push() method:
>
> - one named `og` for items that end with `og` and are 3 letters long or less
> - one named `at` for items that end with `at` that are longer than 3 letters
> - one named `numberFirst` for items that start with numbers
> - one named `numberLast` for items that end with numbers

For my if and else if statements I have them testing if the item is a match to the expression that I created at the top. If it is a match it evaluates as true. I believe either my if statements are wrong or how I created my regular expressions for pattern recognition.

```js
var mainList = ['catalog', 'dog', 'cat', 'hog', 'muskrat', 'World War 3', 'blog', 'frog', '25th of March', 'bat', 'log', 'March 25', 'slog', '10 Downing street', 'flat', 'fat', 'splat', 'blat', 'frat', 'rat', '23 Skidoo', 'Catch 22', '10 4 Good Buddy', 'fog'];
var re = /$og/; //one named 'og' for items that end with 'og' and are 3 letters long or less//
var re2 = /$at/; //one named 'at' for items that end with 'at' that are longer than 3 letters//
var re3 = /[^0-9]/; //one named 'numberFirst' for items that start with numbers//
var re4 = /$[0-9]/; //one named 'numberLast' for items that end with numbers
var arrayOG = [];
var arrayAT = [];
var arrayNumberFirst = [];
var arrayNumberLast = [];

function loop(item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < mainList.length; i++) {
    if (re.test(item) == true && item.length <= 3) {
      arrayOG.push(item);
      console.log(arrayOG);
    } else if (re2.test(item) == true && item.length > 3) {
      arrayAT.push(item);
      console.log(arrayAT);
    } else if (re3.test(item) == true) {
      arrayNumberFirst.push(item);
      console.log(arrayNumberFirst);
    } else if (re4.test(item) == true) {
      arrayNumberLast.push(item);
      console.log(arrayNumberLast);
    }
  }
}
loop();
```

Comment: You're calling `loop()` and not passing in a parameter.

Comment: `item` is a parameter passed to `loop`, you access elements in an array like so `mainList[0]` which is the first element

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `item` as a function parameter in the function definition
`function loop(item) {`
but later when calling the function `loop()` you're not actually passing anything.
item then is undefined for each itteration of the loop.
instead of

```
function loop(item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < mainList.length; i++) {
    ...
  }
}
```

you should try

```
function loop() {
  for (var i = 0; i < mainList.length; i++) {
    const item = mainList[i];
    ...
  }
}
```